# Integrating java with R to render graphs

Tags: java, r, spring-mvc, renjin

I am creating a `Spring MVC` application to render graphs on UI for which I want to pass a value from my `jsp` or `Java` file to `R` based on which it will create a `JSON` or `tsv` which I can use to create graph.

I am using renjin for this. I want to connect R to postgresql through Renjin for which I am using

```
engine.eval("require(RPostgreSQL)");
```

But I am getting the following error;

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is org.renjin.eval.EvalException:
>   Could not load package RPostgreSQL; tried
>   org.renjin.bioconductor:RPostgreSQL, org.renjin.cran:RPostgreSQL

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could use `RCaller` in order to establish a communication between `Java` and `R`.

https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example and the error message you receive from toJSON? If you believe that this is a bug, then you can also open an issue at https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin-json/issues

Comment: I want to run a  R script in Renjin code which contains db connection to postgres but its giving me a dependency error.Which dependency I need to add as I cannot find a suitable location?

Comment: A bit late, but another possibility is to use Java to make the database query, pass the result set into Renjin using the engine's eval function, and manipulate the output from Renjin directly in Java code. A third possibility is to eliminate Renjin altogether and use [PL/R](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/) for a tight integration with PostgreSQL and R.